# grabbing attributes for twig from controller

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, twig

I am using Drupal and have twig for html template. I am super new to this project and see that the have a controller with a function that queries a database and then they return that query for the course page attributes, and I see where the attributes are displayed in the respective course.twig.html.

What I don't see is how they are connected and how the twig.html knows where its attributes are coming from.  I am trying to add some more attributes to the page and don't see how this project is passing the mysql queries to the twig template.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a node.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - node: Full node entity.
 *   - id: The node ID.
 *   - bundle: The type of the node, for example, "page" or "article".
 *   - authorid: The user ID of the node author.
 *   - createdtime: Time the node was published formatted in Unix timestamp.
 *   - changedtime: Time the node was changed formatted in Unix timestamp.
 * - label: The title of the node.
 * - content: All node items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 *   or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use
 *   {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing
 *   of a given child element.
 * - author_picture: The node author user entity, rendered using the "compact"
 *   view mode.
 * - metadata: Metadata for this node.
 * - date: Themed creation date field.
 * - author_name: Themed author name field.
 * - url: Direct URL of the current node.
 * - display_submitted: Whether submission information should be displayed.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 *   The attributes.class element may contain one or more of the following
 *   classes:
 *   - node: The current template type (also known as a "theming hook").
 *   - node--type-[type]: The current node type. For example, if the node is an
 *     "Article" it would result in "node--type-article". Note that the machine
 *     name will often be in a short form of the human readable label.
 *   - node--view-mode-[view_mode]: The View Mode of the node; for example, a
 *     teaser would result in: "node--view-mode-teaser", and
 *     full: "node--view-mode-full".
 *   The following are controlled through the node publishing options.
 *   - node--promoted: Appears on nodes promoted to the front page.
 *   - node--sticky: Appears on nodes ordered above other non-sticky nodes in
 *     teaser listings.
 *   - node--unpublished: Appears on unpublished nodes visible only to site
 *     admins.
 * - title_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main title
 *   tag that appears in the template.
 * - content_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main
 *   content tag that appears in the template.
 * - author_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the author of
 *   the node tag that appears in the template.
 * - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed in front of the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed after the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - view_mode: View mode; for example, "teaser" or "full".
 * - teaser: Flag for the teaser state. Will be true if view_mode is 'teaser'.
 * - page: Flag for the full page state. Will be true if view_mode is 'full'.
 * - readmore: Flag for more state. Will be true if the teaser content of the
 *   node cannot hold the main body content.
 * - logged_in: Flag for authenticated user status. Will be true when the
 *   current user is a logged-in member.
 * - is_admin: Flag for admin user status. Will be true when the current user
 *   is an administrator.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_node()
 *
 * @todo Remove the id attribute (or make it a class), because if that gets
 *   rendered twice on a page this is invalid CSS for example: two lists
 *   in different view modes.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}

{# {{ kint() }} #}

<article id="node-{{ node.id }}" {{ attributes }}>
{{node}}
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if node.field_packaging.value == '1' %}

    {% set image = content.field_image %}
    {% set ce = content.field_tax_credit_hours %}
    {% set goal = content.field_goal %}
    {% set target_audience = content.field_audience %}
    {% set objectives = content.field_objectives %}
    {% set accreditation = content.field_accreditation %}
    {% set disclosure = content.field_disclosure_statement %}
    {# {% set references_old = content.field_references %} #}
    {% set references = content.field_references_par %}
    {% set appendix = content.field_appendix %}
    {% set faculty = content.field_faculty %}
    {% set related_courses = content.field_related_courses %}
    {# set suggested_courses = content.field_suggested_courses #}
    {% set additional = content.field_callout %}
    {% set expiration = node.field_expiration.value %}

    <div class="course-summary row">
      {% if image|render %}
        <div class="course-image small-6 small-offset-3 medium-4 medium-offset-0 columns">
            {{ image }}
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns">
      {% else %}
        <div class="small-12 columns">
      {% endif %}
        <div class="course-introduction">
          <p>Welcome to <em>{{ label }}</em>.</p>
        </div>
        {% if not resource  %}
          {% if ce.0|render %}
            <small class="credit-hours inline-label">Credit hours: {{ ce.0 }} CE</small>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="enroll">
          {% if signIn == "yes"  %}
           {% if regis == true %}
              <a href="appLms/index.php?modname=course&op=aula&idCourse={{ content.field_docebo_course_id.0 }}" class="button large">Go</a>
           {% else %}
              <a href="#" id="regis" rel="{{ content.field_docebo_course_id.0 }}" class="button large">Enroll</a>
           {% endif %}
          {% else %}
            <a href="dashboard/login?lms_id={{ signURL }}" class="button large">Enroll</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% if goal|render or objectives|render %}

      <ul class="tabs some-tabs" data-responsive-accordion-tabs="tabs small-accordion medium-tabs" data-allow-all-closed="true" data-multi-expand="true" id="course-tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#overview" aria-selected="true">Overview</a></li>

        {% if appendix|render %}
          <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#appendix">Appendix</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if references|render %}
          <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#references">References</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if faculty|render %}
          <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#faculty">Faculty</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>

      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="course-tabs">

        <div id="overview" class="tabs-panel is-active course-overview">

          {{ additional|render ? additional }}

          {% if goal|render %}
            <h2 class="field-label">{{ node.field_goal.fielddefinition.label }}</h2>

            {{ goal }}
          {% endif %}

          <h2 class="field-label">{{ node.field_audience.fielddefinition.label }}</h2>

          {% if target_audience|render %}
            {{ target_audience }}
          {% else %}
            <p>interested health-care professionals.</p>
          {% endif %}

          {% if objectives|render %}
            <h2 class="field-label">{{ node.field_objectives.fielddefinition.label }}</h2>
            <p>After completing the activities of this module, you will be able to:</p>
            {{ objectives }}
          {% endif %}

          {% if expiration|render %}
            <p>Please note this module expires on <strong>{{ expiration|date('n/j/Y') }}</strong>.</p>
          {% endif %}

          {% if accreditation|render or disclosure|render %}

            <div class="course-supplements">

              {% if accreditation|render %}

                <h2 class="supplement-title"><a href="#accreditation" class="callout-link" data-toggle="accreditation">Accreditation Statement</a></h2>

                <div id="accreditation" class="callout callout-arrow is-hidden" data-toggler=".is-hidden">

                  {% for i, value in accreditation %}
                    {% set acc_item = node.field_accreditation[i].entity %}
                    {% if acc_item %}
                      <h3>{{ acc_item.title.value }}</h3>
                      {% autoescape false %}
                        {{ acc_item.body.value|replace({'{{ #.## }}': ce.0|escape }) }}
                      {% endautoescape %}
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}

                  <button class="close-button" data-toggle="accreditation">&times;</button>
                </div>

              {% endif %}

              {% if disclosure|render %}

                <h2 class="supplement-title"><a href="#disclosure" class="callout-link" data-toggle="disclosure">Disclosures</a></h2>

                <div id="disclosure" class="callout callout-arrow is-hidden" data-toggler=".is-hidden">
                  {{ disclosure }}
                  <button class="close-button" data-toggle="disclosure">&times;</button>
                </div>

              {% endif %}

            </div>

          {% endif %}

        </div>

        {% if appendix|render %}

          <div id="appendix" class="tabs-panel course-appendix">

            {% if appendix %}

              <ul class="tabs tabs-style-text" data-tabs id="course-appendix-tabs">
                {% for i, value in node.field_appendix.value %}
                  {% set ref_title = node.field_appendix[i].entity.field_title.value %}
                  {% if ref_title %}
                    <li class="tabs-title{{ i == 0 ? ' is-active'}}"><a href="#{{ ref_title|clean_class }}" aria-selected="{{ i == 1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}">{{ ref_title }}</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>

              <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="course-appendix-tabs">
                {% for i, value in node.field_appendix.value %}
                  <div id="{{ node.field_appendix[i].entity.field_title.value|clean_class }}" class="tabs-panel{{ i == 0 ? ' is-active'}}">
                    {% autoescape false %}
                      {{ node.field_appendix[i].entity.field_content.value }}
                    {% endautoescape %}
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>

            {% endif %}

          </div>

        {% endif %}

        {% if references|render %}

          <div id="references" class="tabs-panel course-references">

            {% if references %}

              <ul class="tabs tabs-style-text" data-tabs id="course-references-tabs">
                {% for i, value in node.field_references_par.value %}
                  {% set ref_title = node.field_references_par[i].entity.field_title.value %}
                  {% if ref_title %}
                    <li class="tabs-title{{ i == 0 ? ' is-active'}}"><a href="#{{ ref_title|clean_class }}" aria-selected="{{ i == 1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}">{{ ref_title }}</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>

              <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="course-references-tabs">
                {% for i, value in node.field_references_par.value %}
                  <div id="{{node.field_references_par[i].entity.field_title.value|clean_class}}" class="tabs-panel{{ i == 0 ? ' is-active'}}">
                    {% autoescape false %}
                      {{ node.field_references_par[i].entity.field_content.value }}
                    {% endautoescape %}
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>

            {% endif %}

          </div>

        {% endif %}

        {% if faculty|render %}

          <div id="faculty" class="tabs-panel course-faculty">

            <div class="sections">

              {{ faculty }}

            </div>

          </div>

        {% endif %}

      </div>

    {% endif %}

    {% if related_courses|render %}

      {% set ancillary_1 = node.field_related_courses.fielddefinition.label %}
      {% set ancillary_2 = 'Guidance' %}
      {# set ancillary_2 = node.field_suggested_courses.fielddefinition.label #}

      <ul class="sections sections-border accordion mobile-accordion stacked-tabs" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true" data-multi-expand="true">

        <li class="section accordion-item" data-accordion-item>

          <a href="#" class="accordion-title show-for-small-only">{{ ancillary_1 }}</a>

          {% if related_courses|render %}

            <div class="tiles mobile-accordion-content" data-tab-content>

              <h2 class="field-label section-title hide-for-small-only">{{ ancillary_1 }}</h2>

              <div class="list-items list-format-3">
                {{ related_courses }}
              </div>

            </div>

          {% endif %}

        </li>

        <li class="section accordion-item" data-accordion-item>

          <a href="#" class="accordion-title show-for-small-only">{{ ancillary_2 }}</a>

          <div class="tiles mobile-accordion-content" data-tab-content>

            <h2 class="field-label section-title hide-for-small-only">{{ ancillary_2 }}</h2>

            <div class="list-items list-format-1 list-type-guidance">
              {{ drupal_view('content_feed', 'guidance') }}
            </div>

          </div>

        </li>

      </ul>

      {{ drupal_view('content_feed', 'guidance_modal') }}

    {% endif %}

  {% else %}

    {{ content.body }}

  {% endif %}

</article>
```

Comment: Maybe you could show some code, I guess nobody would be able to answer that question based on this information ...

Comment: And we don't see anything you mention in your question. Without seeing at least some of the code you are describing this question is absolutely unclear.

Comment: Very true. I am so new I really didn't know what to include besides the twig itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should search for preprocess hooks (function yourmodule_preprocess...).  If you are using drupal8 you can set a new variable like this:

```
$vars['myvar'] = 'test';
```

In twig, can be called like this

```
{{ myvar }}
```

Important: it will not work in every function. I use to work it with preprocess functions, but thanks to [@leymannx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2199525/leymannx), we know it works with other hooks too:

> "Not only preprocess hooks can pass variables to templates. Implement
>   hook_theme and then in your controler theme the output and pass
>   variables along to a template"

Answer (score -2):

When you render a twig template in the controller, you can also pass some variables as data. If you want to show that data in the twig template, you call them by their name inside twig functions and language constructs.

That's it in general.

I can not help you more because your question is very generic.